# ¿Cómo puedo encontrar el centroide sin que me de error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Estoy intentando encontrar el centroide de una área de un contorno que marqué con un rectángulo pero cuando añado la parte con los momentos me aparece un error `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero` y dado a eso no me marca el centroide en cada uno de los contornos.

Estoy agregando un `for` dentro del `for` que esta colocando los rectángulos del área encontrada y lo coloco ahí porque ya que se iteró en dibujar el rectángulo de las áreas, quiero que ahora itere para poner el centroide en cada uno de ellos.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('radio.jpg',0)
img = cv2.resize(image,(600,300))
ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(img,49,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
im_flood_fill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(th1)
imgr = cv2.threshold(im_flood_fill_inv,49,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
num_labels, labels_im = cv2.connectedComponents(imgr)

def imshow_components(labels):
    label_hue = np.uint8(179*labels/np.max(labels))
    blank_ch = 255*np.ones_like(label_hue)
    labeled_img = cv2.merge([label_hue, blank_ch, blank_ch])
    labeled_img = cv2.cvtColor(labeled_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    labeled_img[label_hue==0] = 0
    cv2.imshow('labeled',labeled_img)
    ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(labeled_img,49,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
histo = cv2.calcHist([th1],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
plt.hist(th1.ravel(),256,[0,256]); plt.show()

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(th1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

lista = []
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 1000 and area <  10000:
        cv2.drawContours(img, [c], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        lista.append(area)
        resultado = sorted(lista, reverse=True)[0:-2]
        print("Áreas encontradas:", resultado)
   
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area  > 1300 and area < 10000:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        for i in contours:
            momentos = cv2.moments(i)
            cx = int(momentos['m10']/momentos['m00'])
            cy = int(momentos['m01']/momentos['m00'])
            cv2.circle(img,(cx, cy), 3, (0,255,0), -1)

cv2.imshow('contornos', img)
imshow_components(labels_im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Estoy intentando lo recomendado por @Abulafia y esta en lo correcto. Solo que estoy imprimiendo el circulo en la esquina inferior izquierda y si intendo poner cada termino dividido entre 2 me aparece un error, **¿cómo podria colocar el circulo en el centro?**

```
for c in contours:
area = cv2.contourArea(c)
if area  > 1300 and area < 10000:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    rectangle= cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    #Momento
    cv2.circle(img,(x + w, y + h),3, (0,255,0), -1)
```

Comment: Parece que `momentos['m00']` es cero. ¿Seguro que es así cómo hay que calcular el centroide? Al tratarse de rectángulos ¿no bastaría encontrar el promedio entre sus esquinas? Por otro lado tampoco veo la necesidad de otro bucle anidado. Dentro de `for c in contours`, para cada contorno pintas primero el rectángulo y luego el centroide, sin necesidad de volver a iterar por todos

Comment: La variable `y` está indefinida. Por favor, revisar [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @abulafia es correcto, se podría realizar de esta manera solo encontrar la mitad de cada uno de los rectángulos pero ¿cómo es que podría imprimir el resultado en la imagen?.

Comment: ¿No será `cv2.circle(img, ((x+w)/2, (y+h)/2), ...)`?

Comment: Lo intenté pero me dice 'TypeError: integer argument expected, got float' y cuando le agrego un flotante antes pero me da 'TypeError: float expected at most 1 argument, got 2' y realmente ya no se como acomodarlo así.

Comment: Vale, pensé que `circle` admitiría `float` como argumento. Al no ser así lo que tienes que hacer es la división entera, que se hace con `//` en vez de `/`. Es decir, `cv2.circle(img, ((x+w)//2, (y+h)//2), ...)`

Comment: Estuviste bastante cerca estimado Abulafia, solo es hacer la división del ancho y alto. Adjuntaré la solución del problema. Gracias por ayudar nuevamente.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUCIÓN**

Como lo comentó @Abulafia la manera adecuada de encontrár el centro de un cuadrado es tomando el promedio del ancho y altura ya que simplemente es un rectángulo.

Lo único que se hizo fue dividir el ancho y el alto entre 2 para que tome la mitad del alto y ancho del rectángulo.

```
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area  > 1300 and area < 10000:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        rectangle= cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.circle(rectangle,((x+(w//2)), (y+(h//2))),5 , (255,255,255),-1)
```